# Extract login user name from Filemaker-published XSLT pages

Tags: xslt, namespaces, passwords, filemaker

I have published a layout in XSLT format with Filemaker. When a user access this page, he will be prompted for his login details. I want to display his login details after he logged in successfully. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample files that are installed with FileMaker Server.  They set and reference a variable :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$client-user-name"/>
```

You should also be able to get the details from the session if you're using that :

```
fmxslt:get_session_object (String session-name, String name)
```

The code for that comes from the "XSLT Reference.fp7" file installed in the examples folder.